# how to upload a pdf in to localfolder and send via email in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

unable to upload a pdf file to my local folder using codeigniter

I have tried every possible ways to upload a PDF file but i have failed to upload it.The ultimate use of uploading file is to send the attachment along with the mail ,I am getting all other data inside the mail except the PDF.

```
public function resume_send(){

    $img = $this->input->post('resume');
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf';
         $config['max_size'] = '1000';
         $config['max_width'] = '1024';
         $config['max_height'] = '768';
         $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
         $this->load->library('upload', $config);
       // $this->upload->do_upload('resume'); exit;
             if($_POST || $_FILES){
            if(!$this->upload->do_upload('resume')){
            
                    echo $this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');
                      } else {
                                 
                     $w = $this->upload->data();
                     $data = array(
                         'resume' => $w['file_name'],
                         );
                 }
             }
}
```

my view page is like

```
<div class="col-6 col-md-6">
              <i>Upload Resume</i>
              <input style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;padding: 0 !important;margin-top: 15px !important;" type="file" name="resume"  required>
           </div>
```

the file i wish to save in **upload**  folder or without saving also i should get this attachment via email.Any help would be appreciated

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kv28.png)

Comment: a show the form for uploading files (html or Js)

Comment: Do I understand correctly - you want to upload the file to the server first and then send an email with the attachment?